# how do i parse each field seperated by delimiter " | " from a text file .The text file has to be read line by line

Tags: java, parsing, field, bufferedreader, delimiter

Suppose a text file contains 3 fields and the last field is a comma separated multi parameter field . How do i parse each field separated by delimiter " | " from a text file .The text file has to be read line by line. suppose there are 20 lines in the file.Each field has to be parsed recognizing which the whole line displaying all 3 fields has to be printed. I need the java code for this .If possible it should even display the no of parameters in the 3rd field which are separated by commas.

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward, but have you tried anything yet?

Comment: to go off of what Florin said, it will be much easier for you to get a good answer if you show us what you've done.  There are a lot of posts on parsing, and in java it's pretty well documented.  People are really hesitant to just answer questions that you've shown no code for.  Just try putting some code up, and people will help quickly.

Comment: To extend on Florin and Slimmons: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=330

http://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java/

This link provides you different types of reading and writing text files

This shall be your starting point. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bean IO](http://www.beanio.org/).

Configure your XML as something like this

```
<stream name="employees" format="delimited" strict="true">
  <parser>  
    <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
  </parser>
  <record name="test" class="example.Pojo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <field name="member1" />
      <field name="member2" />
      <field name="member3" type="int" />
    </record>
 </stream>
```

Refer [here](http://www.beanio.org/2.0/docs/reference/index.html#Introduction) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something like [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv/).

They give decent examples of how to use it in their [javadocs](http://commons.apache.org/csv/apidocs/index.html), but basically it sounds like you just want to use different field delimiters (see the [CSVFormat class](http://commons.apache.org/csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html)).